# PHP - Multidimensional Array Input ( Having File Type & Text Type ) Form Submission

Tags: php, arrays, forms, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

**View** :

```
<div>
   <input type='file' name="active_board_data[pictures][]">
   <input type='text' name="active_board_data[name][]">
   <input type='text' name="active_board_data[description][]">
</div>
<div>
   <input type='file' name="active_board_data[pictures][]">
   <input type='text' name="active_board_data[name][]">
   <input type='text' name="active_board_data[description][]">
</div>
<div>
   <input type='file' name="active_board_data[pictures][]">
   <input type='text' name="active_board_data[name][]">
   <input type='text' name="active_board_data[description][]">
</div>
```

After Submitting it `var_dump($_POST['active_board_data']);` shows

```
array (size=3)
  'name_description_input' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '<p>sdfv</p>' (length=11)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
  'relevant_details_description_input' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '<p>dsrvsd</p>' (length=13)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '<p>sdfvr</p>' (length=12)
  'pictures' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
```

And `var_dump($_FILES['active_board_data']);` shows

```
array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=1)
      'pictures' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'active_trustees_26-Oct-2014__08_10_00__25408.jpg' (length=48)
          1 => string 'active_trustees_26-Oct-2014__08_10_18__7037.jpg' (length=47)
          2 => string 'active_trustees_26-Oct-2014__08_10_18__3779.jpg' (length=47)
  'type' => 
    array (size=1)
      'pictures' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
          1 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
          2 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      'pictures' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php128F.tmp' (length=23)
          1 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php12A0.tmp' (length=23)
          2 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php12B0.tmp' (length=23)
  'error' => 
    array (size=1)
      'pictures' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 0
          1 => int 0
          2 => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=1)
      'pictures' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 49543
          1 => int 52657
          2 => int 29884
```

Is this the correct way to have have both file and text on same array in php after form submission? Or should I have to change the markup? **Notes:** I am creating the **div** dynamically. PLEASE HELP.Thanks in advance.
Here is a picture of form to submit:
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is correct input for multiple fields.

Comment: but as i have both file and text input how can i have the posted data?

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set on the form tag (you aren't showing that part)? Because that is required when posting a file. Also, the files shouldn't show up in $_POST, it would show up in $_FILES, however the names/structure would be roughly the same where the first file would correlate to the first name/description...etc.

Comment: Please suggest me how to get posted data in php on that particular scenario. `$_POST[]` giving only texts and `$_FILES[]` giving only pictures. @u_mulder. Yes I have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` or otherwise I could not get the `$_FILES[]` results. I need both the files & texts on same index after posting . @Jonathan Kuhn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still access both at the same time, but instead of using a `foreach` structure, you would use a `for` structure, something like this:

```
$szFiles = sizeof ($_FILES['active_board_data']['name']['pictures']);
for ($i=0; $i<$szFiles; $i++)
{
    $file_name   = $_FILES['active_board_data']['name']['pictures'][$i];
    $name        = $_POST['active_board_data']['name'][$i];
    $description = $_POST['active_board_data']['description'][$i];
}
```

An aside: To me, the best part of a framework is using some of it's helper functionality, like the CI file uploader helper system: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html.

Comment: Actually I need to create an album. Where picture, name and description will be given.Those fields are `not required` as sometimes the picture is not available to provide or there is not any description . So how can i get the information if that row has only a name and a description or that row has only a pic and a name? @Hans. I hope I made u understand my problem. Can I solve that with your answer?

Comment: Yes, add a number between the [] for each form, so they look like `active_board_data[pictures][0]`, `active_board_data[name][0]`, etc. You might want to do sizeof on one of the _POST fields instead in that case, too.

Comment: Please @Hans can you improve your `Answer` with the `view` & `controller` code for the problem stated above?

Comment: Nothing changes in the answer; PHP just sees the empty `[]` and adds the number itself. You are forcing it, so you don't have to worry about a missing one if they don't add a file.